# Capturing output with Perl, until a specific pattern is found

Tags: regex, perl, parsing

I feel like I am missing something very simple here, but this is the first time I've needed to do this and am having trouble finding an example.

I have a giant `foreach` loop that walks through output logs and extracts various bits of information based on matching regular expressions. My main problem is that a few larger types of output have a header and footer, like `*** Begin bangle tracking log***` followed by several lines of gibberish and then a `***End bangle tracking log***`.

Is there a way, from within a `foreach` loop, to have an inner loop that stores all the lines until a footer is found?

```
foreach my $line( @parseme )
{
    if( $line =~ m/***Begin bangle tracking log***/ )
    {
        #Help! Push all lines into an array until bangle tracking footer is found.
    }
    if( $line =~ m/Other stuff I am tracking/ )
    {
        #Do other things
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators), which acts as a flip-flop in scalar context:

```
foreach ( @parseme ) {
    if ( /Begin bangle tracking log/ .. /End bangle tracking log/ ) {
        push @array, $_;
    }
    # other stuff...
}
```

I used `$_` for the `foreach` loop because it allows for more concise syntax.  You can use another variable if you like, but then you'll have to write the condition as something like:

```
if ( $line =~ /Begin .../ .. $line =~ /End .../ ) {
```

which might be more readable with some extra parentheses:

```
if ( ($line =~ /Begin .../) .. ($line =~ /End .../) ) {
```

One issue to note about the flip-flop operator is that it remembers its state even after the loop ends.  This means that, if you intend to run the loop again, you *really* ought to make sure that the `@parseme` array ends with a line that matches the `/End .../` regexp, so that the flip-flop will be in a known state when the loop starts the next time.

**Edit:** Per DVK's comment below, if you want to process the collected lines as soon as you reach the footer line, you can do that by checking the return value of the `..` operator, which will end with `E0` on the last line:

```
foreach ( @parseme ) {
    my $in_block = /Begin bangle tracking log/ .. /End bangle tracking log/;
    if ( $in_block ) {
        push @array, $_;
    }
    if ( $in_block =~ /E0$/ ) {  # last line
        # process the lines in @array
        @array = ();
    }
    # other stuff...
}
```

Comment: But how does your code do stiff once the END gets reached? @array will simply get discarded or infinitely appended to!

Comment: @DVK: I was assuming the OP wanted to collect the lines in an array and process them after the loop.  It's possible to process them as soon as the end condition is hit, but that does complicate the code a little bit.

Comment: I've implemented my parser/processor using the range operator and it's solved my problem perfectly.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

You can do that somewhat easily by implementing a primitive state machine:

```
my $inside_bangle = 0; # 0=outside block, 1=inside
my @buffer;
foreach my $line( @parseme ) {
    if  ($line =~ m/***Begin bangle tracking log***/ ) {
        $inside_bangle = 1;
        next;
    }
    if ($line =~ m/***End bangle tracking log***/ ) {
        $inside_bangle = 0;
        # PROCESS @buffer somehow
        next;
    }
    if ($inside_bangle) {
        push @buffer, $line;
        next;
    }
    if ($line =~ m/other stuff i am tracking/ ) {
        #Do other things
    }
}
```

Another option is to use flip-flop (`..`)

Comment: @sarnold - why is it difficult? Once you fix Ilmari's solution to deal with the buffer array, it will be almost the same.

Comment: okay, a two-state state machine isn't _really_ difficult; but the generic technique is useful far beyond the simple `..` operator.

Comment: @sarnold - You're correct. That's one reason I like the technique.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for the `..` operator, which has some magical properties when applied with regular expressions. The following example is stolen from [PLEAC](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_perl/patternmatching.html#AEN309):

```
while (<>) {
    if (/BEGIN PATTERN/ .. /END PATTERN/) {
        # line falls between BEGIN and END in the
        # text, inclusive.
    }
}
```

Within the block, append to your array variable as you see fit.

Comment: There's nothing special about regexps there; something like `if (($_ eq "BEGIN") .. ($_ eq "END")) {` would work just as well.  It's the scalar context that makes `..` act as a flip-flop instead of a list range generator.  (However, the behavior of scalar `..` with _constant_ operands _is_ magic: `5 .. 7` in scalar context is equivalent to `($. == 5) .. ($. == 7)`.)

Comment: Oh, cool; I've only ever seen line numbers and regexps used with `..` in this manner. Thanks @IlmariKaronen.

Answer (score 0):

And now you can store multiple instances of your log snippet, if it occurs more than once (DVK's original code):

```
my $inside_bangle = 0; # 0=outside block, 1=inside
my %buffer;
my $index = 0;
foreach my $line( @parseme ) {
    if  ($line =~ m/***Begin bangle tracking log***/ ) {
        $inside_bangle = 1;
        next;
    }
    if ($line =~ m/***End bangle tracking log***/ ) {
        $inside_bangle = 0;
        $index++;
        # PROCESS @buffer somehow
        next;
    }
    if ($inside_bangle) {
        push @{ $buffer{$index} }, $line;
        next;
    }
    if ($line =~ m/other stuff i am tracking/ ) {
        #Do other things
    }
}
```

Here's what I wrote initially but I thought DVK's code is more readable and neat:

```
open FILE, "<", 'testfile.log';
@parseme = <FILE>;
my $initialize = shift @parseme;
my $startLogging = $initialize =~ m/^Log Start$/ ? 1 : 0; # test if first line of array is start of log
my %storage = ();
my $index = 0;
foreach my $line (@parseme) {
 $startLogging = 1 if $line =~ m/^Log Start$/;
 if ($startLogging == 1) {
  push( @{ $storage{$index} }, $line ) unless $line =~ m/(Log Start|Log End)$/;
  if ($line =~ m/^Log End$/) {
   $startLogging = 0;
   $index++;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: If you are going to steal code almost wholesale from another example, it's polite to explicitly admit to that. BTW, your solution is 100% easier if you simply take my code as-is and do `%buffer{$index++} = @buffer;` instead of `# PROCESS @buffer somehow
`

Comment: Apologies DVK, I meant to add the modifications only, not steal your code, and yes, `%buffer{$index++} = @buffer;` is a nice trick too.